# Supersized and codeigniter connection fails

Tags: codeigniter, supersized

I have an odd problem with using codeigniter and supersized. The plugin works fine and I'm able to load it from the root dir, but when I use it in the MVC workflow it doesn't seem to load the image.

The image i correctly linked and I can see from the code that it is supposed to be there. The only thing I see though, is a black screen.

My code is the standard core example, nothing more/nothing less. Everything is linked properly but still no dice.

Controller

```
function test(){
        $data['img'] = base_url()."../_data/images/bg.jpg";
        $data['main_content'] = 'core_view';
        $this->load->view('/includes/templatepop_view',$data);
}
```

HTML

```
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>../_data/css/supersized.core.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>../_data/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){

                $.supersized({
                                    slides  :   [ {image : '<?= $img;?>'} ]
                });
            });

        </script>



    </head>

<body>

    <div id="content">

    </div>
    ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the template that I used for the header. Basically it loaded jquery twice and a bunch of other stuff, so that interfered with the supersized script. I'll leave it for anyone who might have a similar problem.